# What is in "Other" when looking at Storage

Tags: internal-storage

My HTC Desire 500 is constantly telling me that I have no space for updates. I've cleaned out all cache; am using SD card for storage; yet when I check the storage it shows 2.89GB in "Other".

I can't get in to find out what this is.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It just simply means that the memory i.e 2.89GB is available over your external storage, and yes the reason why your device is showing you that you have no space available because its looking at the device internal storage. I would say to fix this error try moving all the music, videos, apps(if its available for you) to the SD card this error will fix up.